# Understanding a sed example

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I found a solution for extracting the password from a Mac OS X Keychain item. It uses `sed` to get the password from the `security` command:

```
security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga $USER | \ 
  sed -En '/^password: / s,^password: "(.*)"$,\1,p'
```

The code is [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20130722033452283) in a comment by 'sr105'. The part before the `|` evaluates to `password: "secret"`. I'm trying to figure out exactly how the `sed` command works. Here are some thoughts:

I understand the flags `-En`, but what are the commas doing in this example? In the sed docs it says a comma separates an address range, but there's 3 commas.

The first 'address' `/^password: /` has a trailing `s`; in the docs `s` is only mentioned as the replace command like `s/pattern/replacement/`. Not the case here.

The `^password: "(.*)"$` part looks like the Regex for isolating `secret`, but it's not delimited.

I can understand the end part where the back-reference `\1` is printed out, but again, what are the commas doing there??

Note that I'm not interested in an easier alternative to this sed example. This will only be part of a larger bash script which will include some more sed parsing in an .htaccess file, so I'd really like to learn the syntax even if it *is* obscure.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The comma's are random delimiters, they could be something else. `s,^password: "(.*)"$,\1,p ==  s/^password: "(.*)"$/\1/p`

Comment: Exactly what I realised a moment ago. Should I answer my own question?

Comment: Not now there's already 2 people who have done the work for you explaining it & more in detail ;)

Comment: This is a scary command. It gives plaintext versions of stored passwords - and although you get the "do you want to allow application 'security' access to your keychain" dialog, if you click "always allow" you have basically unlocked your keychain (with all stored passwords) for anyone who walks up to your terminal. Yikes.

Comment: I believe it ask for the admin password if you lock the keychain. I'll have to try it.

Comment: No, you're right Floris, looks like it's wide open. Yuk!

Comment: I take it back. 'Always allow' only applies to the specific password. But as long as you know the account name and type you can read any password in the keychain you want, and the info's there to look up EVEN if the keychain is locked! Apple??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is sed command:

```
sed -En '/^password: / s,^password: "(.*)"$,\1,p'
```

- Commas are used as regex delimiter it can very well be another delimiter like `#`:

  ```
  sed -En '/^password: / s#^password: "(.*)"$#\1#p'`
  ```
- `/^password: /` finds an input line that starts with `password:`
- `s#^password: "(.*)"$#\1#p` finds and captures double-quoted string after `password:` and replaces the entire line with the captured string `\1` ( so all that remains is the password )

Comment: Ah, I see. The guy was trying to avoid `/` because it may be in the password.

Comment: Yes that would have been the reason. sed allows any character (including control character) as delimiter.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that a comma would not be in the password but the forward slash would be?

Answer (score 0):

First, the command extracts passwords from a file (or stream) and prints them to stdout.

While you "normally" might execute a `sed` command on all lines of a file, `sed` offers to specify a regex pattern which describes which lines the following command should get applied to.

In your case

```
/^password: /
```

is a regex, saying that the command:

```
s,^password: "(.*)"$,\1,p
```

should get executed for all lines looking like `password: "secret"`. The command substitutes those lines with the password itself while suppressing the outer lines.

The substitute command might look uncommon but you can choose the delimiter in an `sed` command, it is not limited to `/`. In this case `,` was chosen.